# Need a way around this JSON Null exception

Tags: java, json

I fire a query and the result comes in JSON.I set it using setters.here is my Dataclass:

```
private String userstory;
private String task;
private int actual;
private int estimate;
private String ref;
private String uid;
private String tid;
--setters--
```

Here is my main class:

```
for(JsonElement result : taskresponse.getResults())
    {
        JsonObject results = result.getAsJsonObject();
        MyData myData = new MyData(results.get("WorkProduct").getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString(),results.get("Name").getAsString(),
        (int) Double.parseDouble(results.get("Actuals").getAsString()),
        (int) Double.parseDouble(results.get("Estimate").getAsString()),
        results.get("_ref").getAsString(),
        results.get("WorkProduct").getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString(),results.get("FormattedID").getAsString());
        data_list.add(myData);
    }
```

When I get value int in fields "Actuals" and "Estimate" it is working well. But sometimes I get values null as the result from query. Thus I get JSONNULLEXCEPTION.
How should i handle this exception.I ultimately want the fields to be set 0 when query returns null.
Thanks

Comment: i think its because you are parsing the result as Double and then casting to int, i think that the int parsing should be removed `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mod statement like this where if the value is not null it will print the JSON response otherwise return 0

```
Double.parseDouble(results.get("Estimate") == null ? 0 : results.get("Estimates").getAsString(),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the very bad style to pass values in Constructor or Methods. You should always set value first in a local variable and then pass it.

**Check below solution**

```
for(JsonElement result : taskresponse.getResults())
{
    JsonObject results = result.getAsJsonObject();

    private int tempActual = results.has("Actuals") ? results.get("Actuals") != null ? results.getInt("Actuals") : 0: 0;
    private int tempEstimate = results.has("Estimate") ? results.get("Estimate") != null ? results.getInt("Estimate") : 0: 0;;

    //You can use all variables like this

    MyData myData = new MyData(results.get("WorkProduct").getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString(),results.get("Name").getAsString(),tempActual,tempEstimate,
    results.get("_ref").getAsString(),
    results.get("WorkProduct").getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString(),results.get("FormattedID").getAsString());
    data_list.add(myData);
}
```

Comment: In JSONObject there is not getInt...I get cannot resolve method getInt

Comment: Then you can use below line for that:
results.has("Actuals") ? results.get("Actuals") != null ? Integer.parseInt(results.get("Actuals").getAsString()) : 0: 0;

Comment: I tried that but I get cannot parse int 0.0...when I typecasted that it shows same error..jsonnull

Comment: results.has("Actuals") ? results.get("Actuals") != null ? (int) Double.parseDouble(results.get("Actuals").getAsString()): 0: 0;

Answer (score 0):

As you have your Dataclass ,you  create a another ArrayList Data Class like

```
public class ListdataClass {
private ArrayList<Dataclass>  listdata;
//getter and setter for listdata`

}
```

now you Add ObjectMapper Library to read and write Json Data to or from Dataclass

```
ListDataClass listrecord=new ObjectMapper().readValue(taskresponse.getResults().toString(),ListdataClass.class);
```

Now you can loop through Listrecord like

```
    for(Dataclass val:listrecord){
    //get any property value from val Object 
    //There cannot be nullPointerException 

    int estimate=val.getEstimate();
    int actual=val.getActual();
    //etc
    //if json Object has empty value for any element then ObjectMapper will
// fill the default value for that element

    }
```